# SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError When trying to update by Id

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, nodes

I have two models:

```
const CompanyGroup = db.define('company_group', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    field: 'created_at',
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    field: 'updated_at',
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
})
```

and

```
const Company = db.define('company', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    unique: true
  },
  groupId: {
    allowNull: true,
    field: 'group_id',
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'company_group', foreignKey: 'id' }
  }
... other columns
}, {
  paranoid: true,
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
  freezeTableName: true
})
```

I'm trying to create an association between company_group and company by updating column group_id on company table with an existing id and i have the following error:

SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`name_of_my_company`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `company_group_id_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `company_group` (`id`))
...

the query that triggers the error:

```
  async linkGroup(companiesIds, groupId) {
    const linkedCompaniesIds = await this.getlinkedCompaniesIds(groupId)

    const promises = _.map(companiesIds, async (id) => {
      if (_.includes(linkedCompaniesIds, id)) return id

      await this._repository.updateById(id, { groupId })

      return id
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }
```

does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please, try to post the query that triggers the error.

Comment: show `updateById`